# handling big number in vba

Tags: vba, numbers, double

How to handle very large number about 10E22 in VBA?

```vb
dim a, b, c as double
a = 1234567890123456789012
c = a / bit
b = a - (c + 1) * bit
```

I get b = 0

---

As suggested, I change `dim a as double, b as double, c as double`, but it is still off:

```vb
dim a as double, b as double, c as double
a = 1234567890123456789012
c = a / bit
b = a - (c + 1) * bit
```

and I get b = 57344

Answer (score 3):

The only datatype in VBA that can handle such large numbers is [Decimal](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2), which, as a subtype of Variant, cannot be declared directly but must be cast to so your solution would be:

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim c As Variant

a = CDec("1234567890123456789012")
c = a / bit
b = a - (c + 1) * bit
```

Note that the large number must also be written as a String since otherwise it is automatically cast as a Double and precision is lost before the value can be cast as a Decimal.

Comment: Great, this solves the problem. And wanna to add that, looks like we need to define "bit" as variant and make it a cdec too.

Comment: @ThisPaul Well, if you expect it to stay small enough, bit could certainly be any other more common datatype.  The other variables just need to be Variants since they each hold a value that only a Decimal can handle.  Glad I could help, though.  Feel free to accept this as the Answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you write a statement like this:

`dim a, b, c as double`

Only `c` will be the `Double` type all other variables will be `Variant` as you did not explicitly set the type. To set the type you can do 1 of two things

`Dim a as Double, b as Double, c as Double`

Or, a more conventional approach (in my opinion), this:

```
Dim a as Double
Dim b as Double
Dim c as Double
```

For more on datatypes for vba, here is a great article from microsoft ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716185(v=vs.60).aspx))

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yes, you are right, I change the statement as suggested to Dim a as Double, b as Double, c as Double, but it is still wrong... for example  
a=1234567890123456789012  
c = a / 50
b = a - (c + 1) * 50
now I get b=57344

Comment: Read the spec on Double from the Microsoft article, and understand floating point numbers. If you need more precision for integer convert to a decimal, or if you need more precision consider using a modern language like .NET and use BigInteger.